# How do I extract a .tar file on Azure File Share on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, tar, file-sharing

I have a virtual machine in Azure running Ubuntu 18.04. On this machine, I have mounted an Azure File Share as a file share.

Now I'm looking to extract a large file on the mounted drive and it fails. I'm logged in with an admin account.

```
/mnt/folder/data$ tar xvzf data.tar.gz
```

The following error is thrown:

```
tar: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
```

How do I change the permissions on Azure File Share to allow .tar files to be extracted when the admin account is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to extract files inside a storage account. But you could created a script which extracts the files on you machine and moves them back to the storage account.

Comment: Alright. The use case I'm looking for is to do all the work in the mounted drive. If it's not possible to extract files it will be alot of moving files back and forth.